# sbt triggers classloader exception under console and run

Tags: scala, console, sbt, classloader

i have a scala library that i build, test, and deploy (as a jar) using mvn3. The code works correctly under these build and test conditions. i'm currently attempting to use this library in a client project where the client project uses sbt and have discovered a difference between sbt and mvn3. In particular, under the sbt console the deserialization stack does not have access to a classpath that includes the project dependencies. This cause an exception to be called in a code path in my library.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.biosimilarity.lift.model.store.PersistedMonadicKVDBMongoNodeScope$PersistenceScope$BasePersistedMonadicKVDBNode$$anonfun$mget$2$$anonfun$apply$40$$anonfun$apply$41$$anonfun$apply$42
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:604)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1591)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1873)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at com.biosimilarity.lift.model.store.PersistedMonadicKVDBMongoNodeScope$PersistenceScope$MongoDBManifest.asCacheK(PersistedMonadicKVDBMongoNode.scala:445)
...
```

My code captures and serializes a continuation (for a long-lived state machine) and deserializes the continuation to advance the state machine. Under the sbt console, when the continuation is being de-serialized the resolveClass, triggered by a recursive invocation to readObject, fails to find the class (even though the class is in the jar associated with the project dependency). This appears to be because the classloader accessed via the deserialization code path doesn't have access to a classpath that has the project's dependencies on it.

i attempted to fix the problem by defining my own ObjectInputStream and overriding the resolveClass.

```
class DefensiveObjectInputStream( in : InputStream ) extends ObjectInputStream( in ) {
  override def resolveClass( desc : ObjectStreamClass ) : Class[_] = {
     try {
      val currentTccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
      currentTccl.loadClass( desc.getName() )
    } catch {
       case e : Throwable => super.resolveClass(desc);
    }      
  }    
}
```

This doesn't work, however, because the problem is triggered in a recursive call and the classloader accessed in the recursive call doesn't have access to the project's classpath. i've made an open source repro [here](https://github.com/leithaus/wesley). This is pretty much an empty sbt project that just calls into my library to evince the problem. There's a pom.xml file for the equivalent mvn3-based project. It works like a charm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.